# java write class to file

Tags: java, file

This is for a homework I'm doing on my walk learning java.

I'm writing a program and it is all working as expected except the read/write to file.

I have one class named `Medico` that holds only one string (`typeOfMedico`) and one int (`valorFacturado`). `Medico` is a sub class of `Pessoa`. `Pessoa` holds data like name and address. `public class Medico extends Pessoa implements Serializable` is the main function on `Medico`class.

On my main class, named `Clinica`, I ask for user input and at the end of I create a `new Medico` that its added to an Arraylist named `medico`.

For reading and writing to file I've created this class:

```
package clinica;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class FicheiroObjectos {

    private ObjectInputStream iS;
    private ObjectOutputStream oS;

    public void abreLeitura(String nomeDoFicheiro) throws IOException {
        iS = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(nomeDoFicheiro));
    }

    public void abreEscrita(String nomeDoFicheiro) throws IOException {
        oS = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(nomeDoFicheiro));
    }

    public Object leObjecto() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return iS.readObject();
    }

    public void escreveObjecto(Object o) throws IOException {
        oS.writeObject(o);
    }

    public void fechaLeitura() throws IOException {
        iS.close();
    }

    public void fechaEscrita() throws IOException {
        oS.close();
    }

    public void leFicheiroMedicos() {
        Medico medicos;
        while (true) {
            try {
                medicos = (Medico) this.leObjecto();
                Clinica.medicos.add(medicos);
            } catch (EOFException eof) {
                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) {
                System.out.print("\nClassNotFoundException!\nO programa vai terminar\n");
                System.exit(-1);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.print("\nErro ao ler o ficheiro!\nO programa vai terminar\n");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void escreveFicheiroMedicos() {
        try {
            for (Medico medicos: Clinica.medicos) {
                this.escreveObjecto(medicos);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("\nErro ao escrever no ficheiro!\nO programa vai terminar\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

On my main class I've created this two functions:

```
 public static void insereDadosExistentes() {

        try {
            FicheiroObjectos file = new FicheiroObjectos();
            file.abreLeitura("Medicos.dat");
            file.leFicheiroMedicos();
            file.fechaLeitura();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }

    }


    public static void gravarMedicos() {

        try {
            FicheiroObjectos file = new FicheiroObjectos();
            file.abreEscrita("Medicos.dat");
            file.escreveFicheiroMedicos();
            file.fechaEscrita();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("\nErro ao escrever no ficheiro!\nO programa vai terminar\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
}
```

Then added `insereDadosExistentes()` at the beginning of my `main`function and added `gravarMedicos()` just after adding a `Medico` to my `medicos` arraylist.

When I run my program (On the first run, file `Medicos.dat`, does not exist) and create a `Medico`, `Medico` is added to my arraylist and the file `Medicos.dat` is created. Then I stop the program and on the next run, which now haves a `Medicos.dat` file, I get the error:

```
Erro ao ler o ficheiro!
O programa vai terminar
```

The problem is in writing the file or reading the file?
I know the error is given when reading the file but it could be because the writhing to file is not properly executed.

If I try to open `Medicos.dat` I can see some characters but nothing related with the info I input so I don't even know if the file writing is ok.

Remember that all besides file handling is working as expected.

Can you point me In some directions?

favolas

Comment: Please [translate program output](http://translate.google.com/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wT#auto|en|Erro%20ao%20ler%20o%20ficheiro!%0AO%20programa%20vai%20terminar) to English!  That seems to mean.. *"Error reading the file!
The program will end"*.

Comment: Instead of that output line, put `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: I thought it was a fun way to practice Portuguese. This was Portuguese, right? :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson that is exactly what you translated

Comment: @sarnold Yes. You're right :)

Comment: @sarnold Portu..what?  I did not look at Google translate long enough to notice the input language.  And since it came up again, same advice for attribute and method names in source posted to a forum conducted in English.  English (or a close approximation thereof) only, please.

Comment: @Andrew: You need more Brazilian friends! :) Still, I know what you mean, English error descriptions are awesome.

Comment: @sarnold (definitely) OT: From what I know of Brazilians - they seem to know how to enjoy life.  So *everybody* could use some more Brazilian friends.  ;)

Comment: Sorry.Next time will only put English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure that you explicitly close the ObjectOutputStream so that all the data is written.
2. Your problem is an IOException. However, the backtrace will tell you what's going on: trouble opening, reading, what? you can call printStackTrace(), but better you can use a debugging and just look at the stack trace.

Comment: I've closed the ObjectOutputStream and problem persists. printStackTrace() gives me `Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: clinica.Medico; no valid constructor` but looking at my constructor I can't see what the problem is

Comment: Well, does Medico have a no-args constructor? I think that's required.

Answer (score 2):

If you catch an exception dont just write something to system.out but print the stacktrace this will usually give you a clue whats wrong

```
try {
            FicheiroObjectos file = new FicheiroObjectos();
            file.abreEscrita("Medicos.dat");
            file.escreveFicheiroMedicos();
            file.fechaEscrita();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: Are you trying to read and write DATA, or are you trying to serialize and deserialize OBJECTS?

I think all you need to do is open and write to a simple text file:

For example:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/AppendToFile.html

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestFile
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    // Test "append"
    // SOURCE: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/AppendToFile.html
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = 
          new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true));
        out.write("testing: a b c\n");
        out.write("testing: d e f\n");
        out.close();
    } 
      catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
testing: a b c 
testing: d e f
```

Comment: I have to write to a Objects file

Comment: Well then you're going to get a binary file.  With the header string "CAFEBABE" ;)  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: Isn't that for writing text files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java's serialization stuff at all, but this seems "too easy":

```
public void escreveObjecto(Object o) throws IOException {
    oS.writeObject(o);
}
```

How is the object output stream supposed to know what portions of your object needs to be written to disk? Could be that your object contains nothing but computed values that shouldn't be stored. Could be that your object's data needs to be stored completely. Perhaps references to `String` objects should just be dropped... or perhaps those `Strings` should be written to disk.

There must be more to using the ObjectStream stuff than you're showing here -- and [paulsm4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8662868/377270_) shows how writing your own content by hand isn't too bad. Should you be taking that approach instead? Does your class have a defined storage format that you must adhere to?